# Get selected results from a Json file

Tags: c#, json

This is an example of the Json files that I want to work with:

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "totalFeatures": 213,
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "id": "world_contries.1",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "MultiPolygon",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        [
                            [
                                65.53080749511719,
                                37.248600006103516
                            ],
                            [
                                65.6272964477539,
                                37.33319854736328
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            },
            "geometry_name": "geom",
            "properties": {
                "name": "Afghanistan",
                "iso_3_code": "AFG",
                "iso_2_code": "AF",
                "area": 65209,
                "name_1": "Afghanistan",
                "gmi_cntry": "AFG",
                "region": "Asia",
                "pop2005": 25067407,
                "name_12": "Afghanistan"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "id": "world_contries.2",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "MultiPolygon",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        [
                            [
                                19.282489776611328,
                                42.18553924560547
                            ],
                            [
                                19.397319793701172,
                                42.31707000732422
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            },
            "geometry_name": "geom",
            "properties": {
                "name": "Albania",
                "iso_3_code": "ALB",
                "iso_2_code": "AL",
                "area": 2740,
                "name_1": "Albania",
                "gmi_cntry": "ALB",
                "region": "Europe",
                "pop2005": 3153731,
                "name_12": "Albania"
            }
        },
        ]
        }
```

In this type of files I want to have the geometry type and coordinates of all features.

I'm currently using this method to access the file:

```
public static List<string> getCoords(string path)
        {
            //List<string> layers = new List<string>();
            string url = path; 
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.Method = "GET";

            try
            {
                WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
                StreamReader responseStream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
                string responseText = responseStream.ReadToEnd();
                JObject o = JObject.Parse(responseText);
                dynamic array = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseText);
                string type = array["features"].Children()["geometry"]["type"]; 
                response.Close();
            }
            catch (WebException)
            {
                ;
            }
            return null;
        }
```

But it's not working. For instance:

```
array["features"].Children()["geometry"]["type"]
```

This is an Newtonsoft.JSon.Linq.JEnumerable

When I'm debugging in my Visual Studio, in the results view I can read "MultiPolygon", but I do I extract the value?

Comment: Are you sure? you are able to see the value in quick watch. When you access this `array["features"].Children()["geometry"]["type"]` **?**

Comment: in quick watch the falue is Newtonsoft.JSon.Linq.JEnumerable<Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used json2csharp (http://json2csharp.com) to generate some C# classes that match the JSON you provided..

```
public class Geometry
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public List<List<List<List<double>>>> coordinates { get; set; }
}

public class Properties
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string iso_3_code { get; set; }
    public string iso_2_code { get; set; }
    public int area { get; set; }
    public string name_1 { get; set; }
    public string gmi_cntry { get; set; }
    public string region { get; set; }
    public int pop2005 { get; set; }
    public string name_12 { get; set; }
}

public class Feature
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public Geometry geometry { get; set; }
    public string geometry_name { get; set; }
    public Properties properties { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public int totalFeatures { get; set; }
    public List<Feature> features { get; set; }
}
```

You could then modify your code so that it deserializes to the RootObject and it will be alot easier to work with instead of dynamic types...

```
var myObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(responseText);
```

Then you could access it like this...

```
foreach (var feature in myObject.features)
{
    var geometryType = feature.geometry.type;
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply loop through the `JEnumerable` to extract each geometry type :

```
.....
dynamic array = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
var types = array["features"].Children()["geometry"]["type"];
foreach (string type in types)
{
    Console.WriteLine(type);
}
```